# WriteRawJSONString vs ExportString?

Tags: undocumented, json-format

What's the difference between `` Developer`WriteRawJSONString[] `` and `ExportString[]`? I see it used a lot but don't see a difference:

[image]

Comment: You should compare "RawJSON" as the export format instead.  ``temp = RandomReal[1, {400, 20, 20}]; 
Developer`WriteRawJSONString[temp] === ExportString[temp, "RawJSON"]`` returns `True`.

Comment: Right, but what's the differences?

Comment: Also, compare the `Trace` output from the two:  ``TracePrint[
 Developer`WriteRawJSONString[{1, 2, 3}],
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]`` versus the `ExportString` version, and it looks like `ExportString` performs a bunch of validity checks, loads the format, then ends up using functions from the ``Developer` `` package, notably ``Developer`WriteRawJSONStream``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some differences, but as user9490 mentioned, at some level they both might eventually use the same internal functionality. Here are the differences I found:

- `ExportString[_,"JSON"]` will export list of rules and `Association`s as JSON-objects while `ExportString[_,"RawJSON"]` and  `WriteRawJSONString` can't handle list of rules but only work with `Associations` as input.
- there is a difference in how they treat non-ascii characters. `ExportString[_,"RawJSON"]` will handle that as `WriteRawJSONString` does. I don't fully understand the details but think that what `WriteRawJSONString` and `ExportString[_,"RawJSON"]` do looks more consistent than what `ExportString[_,"JSON"]` does.
- `ExportString` is documented functionality while `` Developer`WriteRawJSONString `` is not documented and thus is more likely to be changed or to go away.
- `ExportString` presumably does more validity checks
- According to simple tests `WriteRawJSONString` has better performance than both `ExportString[_,"JSON"|"RawJSON"]`.