# Bug with Json payload with diacritics for HTTPRequest

Tags: character-encoding, json-format, http-functions

Working in the creations of APIs with Mathematica 12.2, I got this problem with diacritics when sending JSON data.

Here is a toy code using [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/).

```
HTTPRequest["https://httpbin.org/anything",
      <|
      Method->"POST"
      ,"Body" -> (<|"textWithDiacritics"-> "àéíóú"|>//ExportString[#, "RawJSON"]&)
        |>
     ]//URLRead[#, "BodyBytes"]&//FromCharacterCode//ImportString[#, "RawJSON"]&
```

[image]

I found this [related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83005), It seams to be a bug in ExportString for RawJSON.

Any suggestions on how to get around this case?

[Cross post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2216425) in Wolfram Community

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ExportString JSON produces UTF8 encoded json string, if put as `HTTPRequest` body it will undergo another encoding unless you prevent it with an option:

```
HTTPRequest[..., CharacterEncoding -> None]
```

It is analogous to the double decoding issue which you address with `bodybytes//FromCharacterCode//ImportString`.

---

### Exchanging JSON via http requests

This is very common these days so for the record:

#### Building requests (for URLRead input):

```
HTTPRequest[
  url_
, <|
    "ContentType" -> "application/json"
  , "Body"        -> ExportString[ jsonCompliant_String, "RawJSON"]
  , "Method"      -> "POST"
  , "Headers"     -> {"Accept"->"application/json"} (* less important *)
  |>
, CharacterEncoding -> None
]
```

#### Receiving requests ( for APIFunction )

I will skip the part of handling different payloads or error handling, just assuming the incomming request is on generated as above will need:

```
APIFunction[
  {}
, Function[whatever (*we don't care about query params*)
  , HTTPRequestData["BodyBytes"] // FromCharacterCode //
      ImportString[#, "RawJSON"]& //
      doSomethingWithAssoAndGenerateResponse
  ]
]
```

#### Building responses (* in API/FormFunctions *)

For `APIFunction` etc there is a nice wrapper `ExportForm` which works with `GenerateHTTPResponse` which is called on the result of APIFunction's function.

So a quick way:

```
  APIFunction[{}, ExportForm[association, "RawJSON" ]& ]
```

And a longer way:

```
HTTPResponse[
    ExportString[association_ , "RawJSON" ]
  , <| "ContentType"->"application/json" |>
  , CharacterEncoding -> None
  ]
```

I wish there was ExportForm support for building HTTPRequests, I even asked WRI, the status is 'maybe'.

#### Parsing responses (* what URLRead needs to do *)

Worth to mention that `URLExecute` does it well wrt encoding but I always need more controll on status codes etc so I need to use `URLRead`.
So as you mentioned:

```
URLRead[...]["BodyBytes"]& // FromCharacterCode//ImportString[#, "RawJSON"]&
```

I would not try to decode `"Body"` because it is very unclear what the body is according to developers, the behavior of `"Body"` worsened in 12.2 it became even less predictable. So `URLExecute` or `"BodyBytes"` are the way to go.

### More reading:

[HTTPRequest syntax problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161654/5478)

[Who is to blame: parsing UTF8 encoded JSON HTTPResponse fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154245/who-is-to-blame-parsing-utf8-encoded-json-httpresponse-fails)

Comment: This is cool too. Now I don't know which one to accept! :)

Comment: @Murta thanks for the accept. I added a guideline section so you won't be sorry :)

Answer (score 8):

I've had luck using the functions `WriteRawJSONString` and `ReadRawJSONString` from `Developer` context. Check out: [WriteRawJSONString vs ExportString?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134705/writerawjsonstring-vs-exportstring)

```
HTTPRequest[
    "https://httpbin.org/anything", <|Method -> "POST", 
     "Body" -> (<|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|> // 
        Developer`WriteRawJSONString)|>] // 
   URLRead[#, "BodyBytes"] & // 
  FromCharacterCode // Developer`ReadRawJSONString

(* <|"args" -> <||>, "data" -> "{
    \"textWithDiacritics\":\"àéíóú\"
}", "files" -> <||>, "form" -> <||>, 
 "headers" -> <|"Accept" -> "*/*", 
   "Accept-Encoding" -> "deflate, gzip", "Content-Length" -> "38", 
   "Content-Type" -> "text/plain;charset=utf-8", 
   "Host" -> "httpbin.org", "User-Agent" -> "Wolfram HTTPClient 12.2",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" -> "Root=1-604a65d2-560dfd4155a830d409b373c9"|>,
  "json" -> <|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|>, "method" -> "POST", 
 "origin" -> "165.254.183.48", 
 "url" -> "https://httpbin.org/anything"|> *)
```

Comment: This is great, tks Chuy.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, the issue is in how `ExportString` is handling the diacritics. We can see that it botches them, but the function being used under the hood *doesn't*

```
(<|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|> // ExportString[#, "RawJSON"] &)

"{
    \"textWithDiacritics\":\"Ã Ã©Ã­Ã\.b3Ãº\"
}"

<|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|> // Developer`WriteRawJSONString

"{
    \"textWithDiacritics\":\"àéíóú\"
}"
```

That issue can be traced back to the way `ExportString` works (I think): it opens an `OutputStream`, uses a standard exporter to write there, then reads back into Mathematica as a `"String"`, because it's fast.

We can see that issue clearly if we mimic that approach:

```
meh = OpenWrite[];
Developer`WriteRawJSONStream[meh, <|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|>];
Import[Close[meh], "String"]

"{
    \"textWithDiacritics\":\"Ã Ã©Ã­Ã\.b3Ãº\"
}"

meh = OpenWrite[];
Developer`WriteRawJSONStream[meh, <|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|>];
Import[Close[meh], "Text"]

"{
    \"textWithDiacritics\":\"àéíóú\"
}"
```

So what's the solution? Well, I *think* you can just leave the body as an expression and Mathematica will write it out as a raw JSON string for you, i.e. this works for me

```
HTTPRequest[
    "https://httpbin.org/anything",
    <|Method -> "POST", 
     "Body" -> <|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|>
     |>
    ] // 
   URLRead[#, "BodyBytes"] & // FromCharacterCode // 
 ImportString[#, "RawJSON"]["form"] &

<|"textWithDiacritics" -> "àéíóú"|>
```

But in any case, any of the existing solutions provide real answers, this was mostly just to point how what's going wrong.